# Can't call to relation property in php-MysqliDb

Tags: twig, php-mysqlidb

The product object has the relation to category object.

```
protected $relations = [
        'category' => ['hasOne', '\Module\Shop\Model\Category', 'cat_id'],
];
```

https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class#objects-mapping

However if i print `{{ product.category.name }}` , it will print `product` , not the category object, due to the `__call` method of php-Mysqlidb.

So twig can't call to lazy load properties ?

Comment: `Mysqlidb`? Nothing in your code suggests that you are using this old library

Comment: @Dharman the code syntax, object has `$relations` , will be lazy execute the subquery, and twig can't access to it phug can

Comment: See [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#variables) which calls `twig` executes. Guess u'll need to check out what calls to the magic method `__call` and create extra hook